# How to declare template class variable with base param and then initialize it in case statement c++

Tags: c++, class, templates, types

```
MyArray<?base?> a;
switch (var)
{
case 1:
    a = MyArray<int>("a");
    break;
case 2:
    a = MyArray<double>("a");
    break;
}
```

How can I declare a template class variable with `?base?` type parameter, and then initialize it in one of the case statements in c++?

Comment: What is `?base?`?

Comment: It would be possible if those classes were polymorphic. Or you can utilize something like `variant` or `any`.

Comment: something like c# Object class

Comment: @keklolmdek There's no such thing like C#'s or Java's `Object` class in c++.

Comment: I think that the answer very heavily depends of what do you what to use this code to. I can think of a few different solutions and each of them will be suitable for different situation. Could you provide some complete example of how do you want to use object `a` after the switch statement?

Comment: I don't really understand why this question is that heavily downvoted. It's pretty clear what the OP wants to achieve, and such question isn't unnatural to come up for a person who's already familiar with Java of C# generics.

Answer (score 1):

> How to declare template class variable with base param and then initialize it in case statement c++?

Unlike than in the C# or Java programming language there's no common `?base?`or `Object` class for the representation of primitive types like `int` or `double`.

But even then, `MyArray<int>`, `MyArray<double>` and `MyArray<Object>` would be completely distinct types, which could not be casted to each other directly.

---

One way I see to do what you want is

```
 class MyArrayBase {
 public:
      MyArrayBase(std::string s);
      virtual ~MyArrayBase() {}
      virtual void foo() = 0;
 };

 template<typename T> 
 class MyArray : public MyArrayBase 
 {
 public:
      MyArray(std::string s) : MyArrayBase(s) {}
      void foo() {
          // Do something
      }
 };
```

---

```
 std::unique_ptr<MyArrayBase> a;
 switch (var)
 {
 case 1:
     a = std::make_unique<MyArray<int>>("a");
     break;
 case 2:
     a = std::make_unique<MyArray<double>>("a");
     break;
 }

 // Call foo()
 a->foo();
```

The techique described above is used in the same situation without having to deal with template classes BTW.